# str.strip() error, my strip does not remove all the quotation marks from my str

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, discord.py, strip

Error Output:

This is the current output of my code

```
money': 2200
```

Expected Output:

```
money: 2200
```

Current Code:

```
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    # try:
    #     with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    #         # Read a single record
    #         sql = "SELECT xp_points FROM players WHERE userid = %s"
    #         values = member.id
    #         cursor.execute(sql, values)
    #         result = cursor.fetchone()
    # except Exception as e:
    #     print(f"An error Occurred>  {e}")
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            monsql = "SELECT money FROM players WHERE userid = %s"
            value = member.id
            cursor.execute(monsql, value)
            monresult = str(cursor.fetchone())
            stripped = str(monresult).strip("{'}")
            print(stripped)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error Occurred>  {e}")
    # e = discord.Embed(title="Stats Command", color=member.color)
    # e.add_field(name="Experience Points", value=result)
    # e.add_field(name="Coins Gained", value=monresult)
    # await ctx.send(embed=e, content=None)
```

WHy is my code only stripping/removing one quotation mark of the string? Shouldn't it be stripping all the quotation marks it finds? Hope someone can help me  with this.

Comment: Use `str(monresult).replace("'", "")` instead of strip

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate it my man.

Comment: I have put up an answer which you can validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stripped = str(monresult).replace("'", "")
```

The strip method causes problems as you don’t really know what will be stripped sometimes, so in newer versions of python there will be `removeprefix` and `removesuffix`. using `replace()` will be easier, and you can even specify the number of occurrences that should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Use replace() instead of strip().